# ¿Por qué TypeScript no me muestra los errores al escribir el código?

Tags: typescript

Actualmente estoy comenzando a leer documentacion de typeScript sin embargo en ningun momento me muestra los errores en tiempo real.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo cuando intento transpilar si me muestra el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado desinstalar e intalar nuevamente typescript pero sigue igual ¿alguien sabe porque puede estar pasando esto o como solucionarlo? ¿quizas sea algo en le tsconfig.json?

Comment: Eso tiene que ver con el IDE, cual estas usando tu?? VS Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás usando Visual Studio Code, en este caso dentro del archivo [`settings.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson), asegura que tienes definido:

```
"typescript.validate.enable": true
```

De esta forma habilitas los mensajes de advertencia.

Revisa:
[Configuración de usuario y espacio de trabajo](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

Comment: Excleente amigo era eso, muchisimas gracias!